# x86 and x64 System.Data.SQLite issue

Tags: .net, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I found a lot of questions about this problem but did not find any answers. I have a rather strange problem. When I add a 32bit reference for `System.Data.SQLite` to my project it only works on x86 platform, and that should be fine by me as my app will run only on 32bit Windows. But when I try to run the app on 32bit Windows it throws the exception `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'`. Then I downloaded 64bit version of `System.Data.SQLite dll`. Then I could start debug with ANY CPU target platform, but couldn't run the app on my 32bit XP that had the same error `Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite'`.

I'm going a bit crazy. I don't know it is of any relevance, I don't see any, but target framework for my app is .NET 4.0 and I tried every combination of `System.Data.SQLite` (.NET 2.0, .NET 3.5, .NET 4.0) 32bit and 64bit version, nothing helps. Here is how my config file looks like:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
      <remove invariant="System.Data.SQLite"/>
      <add name="SQLite Data Provider" invariant="System.Data.SQLite" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for SQLite" type="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory, System.Data.SQLite"/>
    </DbProviderFactories>
  </system.data>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="VetStationConnection" connectionString="Data Source=VeterinaryStation.s3db" providerName="System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteFactory"/>
  </connectionStrings>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution. Actual I found where I made mistake :) i downloaded binaries that are no statically linked and it required visual c++ runtime. So solution for this is to install visual c++ runtime or download system.data.sqlite statically linked binaries :D

Comment: Thanks so much for posting this, for me it was the missing piece!