# Download Yahoo Finance Data - assembly 'System.Data.SQLite

Tags: c#, .net, sqlite, .net-assembly

I am trying to implement a code found on internet and I want to change it, however, I cannot debug it, because it displays this information :

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.46.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
```

I am under Win 7 with 64bits.

I guess that I have to change the assembly sqlite, I try to find on their website, but they give a lot of file '.exe' which create hundred other files, where my noobie level of C# cannot handle.

Any idea to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is a complaint about the bitness (32 vs. 64) of the target assembly, or one of the DLLs it relies on.  Something is the wrong bitness.

You state you're using a 64-bit version of Win7, therefore you want one of the "Setups for 64-bit Windows" from the [SQLite Download Page](http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki), and for the appropriate version of the .NET Framework that you are targeting.

Also, take a look at this fellow's resolution - was missing the C++ runtime:
[x86 and x64 System.Data.SQLite issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8965880/x86-and-x64-system-data-sqlite-issue)

Comment: Thanks I will look at it tonight and tell you you are my high !